# Can two master pages be applied to one page in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

Is there a way of applying two master pages in one page?

I want to make an adjustable InDesign template for a report that could be used for various projects. So I want to have one of the master pages applied to all the pages of the report and the second master page to be applied again in all the pages but I want to have the ability to override only the items of the second master page.

Answer (score 5):

No, multiple masters cannot be applied to a single page. Conceptually, master pages are alternate templates — an actual page in your document can only use 1 template at a time.

Now, you can do multiple master pages where subsequent master pages add to earlier master pages.

So, let's say you start with A-master. You can setup your basic page grid, etc. there. Then you add B-Master. When you create B-master you can choose for it to use A-master as its starting point. So the grid, etc. you have setup on A will show up in B. But you can then add more things, page numbers or graphics or a header to B without changing A. Changes you make to A will show up in B.

[image: master examples]

In this example, A-Basic Page Grid contains the rows, columns, and other guides that B,C, & D all are built on top of (see how they have the "A" over their pages, that means they are referencing A-Basic Page Grid).

[image: making one master the child of another]

Here you can see how B is based on A — Based on Master "A-Basic Page Grid"

These can continue to have parent/child relationships, so master C could be based on B, and thus be the grand-child of A... make sense?

If I understand your question, I think conceptually this should allow you to do what you want to.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to work is to create a separate Master Page for each different in-document page appearance. Even if there is only a small difference between one set of Master Pages and another, this is the most straightforward way to have slightly different layouts within your document. [[1]](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/master-pages.html)

Simply create your primary Master Pages. Then highlight those Masters in the "Pages" window, right click on them, and choose "Duplicate Master Pages" in the drop down menu that appears.

[image: Screenshot of Pages Window]

From there, edit your new Master Pages. Drag and drop them onto the in-document pages you want slightly different.